# Find all solutions to $2 x + 3 y + 4 z = 10$

Tags: combinatorics, integer-programming

I do not have a background in math, and am wondering what type of question this is.  I looked combinatorics optimization, and the knapsack problem, but found the vocabulary too dense.

The problem:
Given the following array A = [2,3,4], what is the best way to find all arrays of coefficients of A that give the product equal to 10.

```
Ex: 
A = [2,3,4]
B = [5,0,0]
C = A * B = [10,0,0]
Sum of C = 10
```

All Answers: [5,0,0], [3,0,1], [2,2,0], [0,2,1]
Just to restate, what is the best way to find the above answers (keeping in mind the target product could be large, like 100,000)?

Comment: Allow the second array to be given by $[x,y,z]$ then you condition is equivalent to $2x+3y+4z=10$ which has a LOT of solutions, and by a lot I mean infinite solutions as this is the equation of a plane in 3D space. You need more constraints to have a finite set of answers.

Comment: You say "*All answers*" but what about things like $[1,1,\frac{5}{4}]$?  Are you specifically interested in solutions with non-negative integer entries?  Also, your "matrix product" appears to be the dot product (*inner product*) of two vectors and is not the usual product of matrices.  Your example you have $A\cdot B = 10$ not $A\cdot B=[10,0,0]$.

Comment: Looking for non-negative solutions, you could approach via generating functions.  In your case, the coefficient of $x^{10}$ of the expansion of $(1+x^2+x^4+x^6+\dots)(1+x^3+x^6+x^9+\dots)(1+x^4+x^8+\dots)$ will tell you how many solutions exist.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments so far.  Some of my vocab maybe off in regards to matrix multiplication.  What ever you would call the following [1,2,3] * [2,2,2] = [2,4,6], is what I was trying to describe. To clarify, I would like all non-negative, integer solutions (no fractions).  Also, by saying 'the best' way I mean a method other than brute force iteration.

Comment: $\displaystyle{{1 \over 10!}\lim_{z \to 0}\,\,{\mathrm{d}^{10} \over \mathrm{d}z^{10}}\left\lbrack{1 \over \left(1 - z^{2}\right)\left(1 - z^{3}\right)\left(1 - z^{4}\right)}\right\rbrack = 5}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find all **nonnegative integer** solutions, i.e.,

$$\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb N^3 \mid 2 x + 3 y + 4 z = 10 \}$$

then you can simply brute-force it. In [Haskell](http://tryhaskell.org),

```
λ filter (\(x,y,z)->2*x+3*y+4*z==10) [ (x,y,z) | x <- [0,1..5], y <- [0,1..4], z <- [0,1..3]] 
[(0,2,1),(1,0,2),(2,2,0),(3,0,1),(5,0,0)]
```

Hence, there are $5$ nonnegative integer solutions

$$\{ (0,2,1), (1,0,2), (2,2,0), (3,0,1), (5,0,0) \}$$

A much smarter way of finding all nonnegative integer solutions is to write $x = 5 - \frac{3}{2} y - 2 z$. Let

$$y = 2 m_1 \qquad \qquad z = m_2$$

where $m_1 \in \{0,1,2\}$ and $m_2 \in \{0,1,2,3\}$. Hence, the solution set can be parametrized as follows

$$\begin{bmatrix} x\\ y\\ z\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 5\\ 0\\ 0\end{bmatrix} +  m_1 \begin{bmatrix} -3\\ 2\\ 0\end{bmatrix} + m_2 \begin{bmatrix} -2\\ 0\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

In [Haskell](http://tryhaskell.org),

```
λ filter (\(x,y,z)->x>=0 && y>=0 && z>=0) [ (5-3*m1-2*m2,2*m1,m2) | m1 <- [0,1..2], m2 <- [0,1..3] ]
[(5,0,0),(3,0,1),(1,0,2),(2,2,0),(0,2,1)]
```

We obtain the same $5$ solutions, though in a different order. However, we searched over a set of cardinality $12$, rather than one of cardinality $120$, as previously.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I should have been more specific and said that I want to avoid brute force iteration.  I am dealing with something more like [1,2,4,3,2] * [a, b, c, d, e] == 500, and would like to make it somewhat snappy.  I was wondering if there was a known shortcut to this type of approach.  I suppose this is a programming question as well as a math question.

Comment: @O.D.P If you have one linear equation with $n$ unknowns, then you have $n-1$ degrees of freedom. If you want to find **all** solutions, you have to travel along this affine space of dimension $n-1$, which isn't that much better than brute-forcing in $n$ dimensions.

Comment: @O.D.P I have updated my answer. The new approach is 10x more efficient.

Comment: Very cool.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Any vector on the following **plane** in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be the answer

$$2x+3y+4z=10$$

[image]

Comment: How did you calculate the dimensions of this plane? Could one make a similar graphic (or a graphic at all ) for, say, 6 dimensions?

Comment: Since our vectors just have 3 components so we are in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Graphical visualization is not possible for $n \ge 4$.